# add datetime picker to shipping section of optimised checkout in BigCommerce

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I have successfully added java script for a basic bootstrap date time picker on the optimised checkout page on BigCommerce. The issue I face is that the container that I added sits at the bottom of the checkout page.

I can't find the file that controls the checkout content so I can put the container just above the order comments box, and additionally add the results of the date-time picker to the comment box on checkout.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is such a common use case, I wish they had built in support for it.  Have you considered posting to the Ideas section of the forum to get them to add it to Cornerstone?

Comment: Have you considered adding a custom address field (via Control Panel) which gets added to the shipping address section?

Comment: So I worked out that the custom fields can be used for adding a date field and also a pick list to cover delivery times, but sadly my problem gets complicated after that. What I didn't explain is that I need to use javascript with the time picker so that I can implement cut off times for the next delivery slot so that customers can't pick a slot that is within the current hour.